# Safe Sparring Spear

Tags: sparring, weapons, safety

Is there any safe sparring staff which can simulate a spear, which you can use with minimal protection? I've talked to friends, and even rattan staffs seem to smart and leave bruises.

I guess you could cover the ends with foam or something, to make it hurt less (since that's where all the leverage and poking is).

Comment: You might want to check out this episode of Kung Fu Quest where they go to learn Bajiquan and see several schools doing spear training.  At the very end you can see them doing training with heavy long spears, but intense home made armor for protection: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTxzd_LKIew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Home-made**:
I have utilized a wooden staff and put a layer or two of pipe foam on the end.  It's relatively cheap and provides padding to blunt hits so long as you don't jab it really hard.  I utilized electrical tape to fully wrap it which helps prevent slippage (you need to keep it a solid piece and start at the top wrapping and go down and then wrap the wood a few times to hold the padding steady).  The end looks funky and is bigger than expected, but due to the light weight of the foam and the tight wrapping of the tape it had virtually no extra drag, stayed in place, and padded all hits.  The poking part was the worst though as it's such a small area and hard to pad it enough.  I would probably add some extra to the tip if I re-did it.

**Ingredients**:

- any staff (non-slick might be best)
- Pipe insulation (i.e. http://www.homedepot.com/b/Plumbing-Pipe-Insulation/N-5yc1vZbuy9)
- Electrical tape